# How to make 2012 by using 2, 0, 1, 2?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

How to make $2012$ by using $2, 0, 1, 2$?

Allowed Operations:

Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division, $!$ (factorial), subfactorial ( $!n$), primorial (product of the first $n$ primes), square root($\sqrt{}$), exponentiation ($a^{b}$), double factorial ($n!!$), triple factorial ($n!!!$), radical and ceiling function, decimal point, tetration (iterated exponentiation), infinite roots.

Brackets and parenthesis () are also allowed.

Comment: 2012 is 2,0,1,2 concatenated (did I spell it correctly?)

Comment: Yea, if concatenation is allowed, then 2012 = 2.0.1.2 where . is concatenation operation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do it

> $$-1 -\left \lceil-\sqrt{ \left(\left(\left\lceil \sqrt{((2 + 0!)!)!!!} \right\rceil!!\right)!!\right) \times 2 } \right \rceil = -1 -\left \lceil-\sqrt{ \left(\left(5!!\right)!!\right) \times 2 } \right \rceil = 2012$$

Answer (score 3):

A shortened version based on @hexomino's nice solution:

> $$  -0! - \left \lceil - \sqrt{ \left(\left( \left( \frac{1}{.2} \right) !!\right)!!\right) \times 2 } \right \rceil = 2012 $$

I don't understand why the ceiling function is allowed, but why the floor function should not be allowed. If it is allowed you could shorten it further and arrange it to:

> $$ \left \lfloor \sqrt{ \left(\left( \left( \frac{1}{.2} \right) !!\right)!!\right) \times 2 } \right \rfloor - 0! = 2012 $$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possibility

> We have
>  $$6!!!=18, \lfloor\sqrt{(6!!!)}\rfloor=4, 4!!=8, 8!!=384, \lceil\sqrt{(8!!)}\rceil=20, 20!!!=4188800, \lfloor \sqrt{(20!!!)}\rfloor=2046$$
>  and
>  $$6!!!=18, \lceil\sqrt{(6!!!)}\rceil=5, 5!=120, \lfloor\sqrt{(5!)}\rfloor=10, !10=1334961, \lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{(!10)}}\rceil=34$$

Hence

> $$\lfloor\sqrt{\left(\lceil \sqrt{\left(\left(\lfloor\sqrt{\left(\left(0!+2\right)!\right)!!!}\rfloor\right)!!\right)!!}\rceil\right)!!!}\rfloor - \lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{!\left(\lfloor\sqrt{\left(\lceil\sqrt{\left(\left(1+2\right)!\right)!!!}\rceil\right)!}\rfloor\right)}}\rceil = 2046-34 = 2012$$

Answer (score 2):

My approach relies primarily on the Primorial and Multi-factorial operations. To simplify and make it easier to read, I am using the notation P(n) to represent the primorial of n.

> $P\left(\left \lceil \sqrt{P(2)!!!} \right \rceil \right) = 2310$

> $P\left(\left \lceil \sqrt{\left \lceil \sqrt{P\left(P(1)\right)!!!}\right \rceil !!!} \right \rceil \right) = 210$

> $\left \lceil \sqrt{\left \lceil \sqrt{P(2)!!}\right \rceil!!}\right \rceil = 11$

> $\left \lceil \sqrt{\left \lceil \sqrt{P\left(P(0!)\right)!!!}\right \rceil!!}\right \rceil!! = 8$

> $P\left(\left \lceil \sqrt{P(2)!!!} \right \rceil \right) - P\left(\left \lceil \sqrt{\left \lceil \sqrt{P\left(P(1)\right)!!!}\right \rceil !!!} \right \rceil \right) - \left(\left \lceil \sqrt{\left \lceil \sqrt{P(2)!!}\right \rceil!!}\right \rceil \times \left \lceil \sqrt{\left \lceil \sqrt{P\left(P(0!)\right)!!!}\right \rceil!!}\right \rceil!!\right) = 2012$

Feel free to let me know if there are any mistakes!

Comment: I'm not clear about your P(n). I think P(2)=2,hence P(2)!!!=2 and finally
$$P\left(\lceil \sqrt{P(2)!!!} \rceil \right) = 2$$

Comment: But the Primorial of n is the product of the first n primes, so P(2) = 2*3 = 6

Comment: oh, I see, I misunderstood the definition, +1 for your solution